# ng-repeat dynamic variable name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am implementing ng-repeat to create elements for a bootstrap accordion interface.

I have ng-repeat working however the issue I have is that I need to dynamically create the ID in order to target the accordion element individually.

My ng-repeat HTML block references:

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#products-accordion" href="#collapseOne">
```

And lower down references:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

For this to work correctly, collapseOne needs to be dynamic - collapse1, collapse2 etc. How is it possible to iterate values in ng-repeat? "collapse" + i basically is what Im trying to achieve.

Secondly, only the first item in the ng-repeat list requires the "in" class on this line:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

This ensures the first item is opened.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-repeat`s built-in `$index`. (Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

So it would look like this:

```
<div id="collapse_{{ $index }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

Which would create:

```
<div id="collapse_0" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div id="collapse_1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

Etcetera.

For opening the first `div` by default I think you can use `ng-class` like this:

```
<div id="collapse_{{ $index }}" ng-class="{ in : $index == 0 }" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Comment: great thanks that makes sense I will implement that now. Do you have any idea how I might be able to only apply that css class on first iteration? imagine if I can access the index[0] that would identify the first pass... but how to act on that inline

Comment: You want to add the `in` class to only the first div?

Comment: yes only on the first pass of the ng-repeat as that means if 5 of the divs render the first 1 will be open as its a bootstrap accordion

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the answer to the second part of your question. I think it should work like this.

Comment: Thats great I swapped it to 0 assuming its zero based array and thats seems to have cracked it - thanks again peter!

Comment: Oh wow, yes of course that should be 0. Good thing you're at least paying attention since I obviously wasn't.... Edited it now.