# Dynamically change the Bootstrap panel link names (open and close panel) for AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How can I set up my Bootstrap panel collapse, to dynamically increment with `AngularJs ng-repeat`?

**In other words, change this:**

`data-target="#collapseOne"`,
and this:
`<div id="collapseOne">`

**to something like (mind the sudo code):**

This:
`data-target="#collapse" + "+="`
and this:
`<div id="collapse" + "+=">`

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">{{product.productName}}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">{{product.productDescription}}</div>
                <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482921/ng-repeat-dynamic-variable-name. My Apologies.

Comment: WHY down-vote me? What is wrong with my question? It is like there are trolls who just down-vote for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ng-attr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) to bind it with Angular:

```
<a ... ng-attr-data-target="{{'#collapseOne' + yourId}}">
    {{product.productName}}
</a>
```

If you are working with `ng-repeat`, you can use [`$index`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to set this ID.
It will works for every attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. I found this simpler solution as posted in my answer.

Comment: @onmyway Concatening $index is great, but as I said, biding with `{{ }}` may not work for every attribute. Using `ng-attr` is cleaner (I also use $index in my answer).